# How to set a TP and SL using Limit and Stop orders in FIX API/QuickFIX/n

Tags: quickfix, fix-protocol, quickfixn

I am using QuickFIX/n to write an application. I followed an example from the documentation([QuickFIX/n Example](https://github.com/connamara/quickfixn/blob/master/Examples/TradeClient)). Using this example I got the application working, but I want to know how to get the market price into my trading session so that I can set Limit and Stop Orders that act as SL/TP for my market orders.

The problem is I don't know how to get the pricing data into my trading application. Settings for the trading session and pricing sessions are different(even the host address, port, username, password).

I  know that I need to have 2 sessions, pricing and trading sessions running simultaneously in the same application where I can access the pricing details such as Bid/Ask price so that I can set the limit/stop orders, but I don't know how to achieve this.

If someone can provide some assistance in this regards it would be great.
(an example application would be brilliant)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: In your quickfix app you have a function "fromApp" all inbound message is going there (from all your sessions)

You just need to make a switch on the fix msg type and process the message like you want

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But my question is how to make 2 sessions from the same application(one for trading and another for pricing)

Comment: You can set multiple sessions on the config file http://quickfixn.org/tutorial/configuration.html
Instanciate the initiator with this config file and your app, the messages from both session will go through "fromApp". Im using the python version of quickfix, but this is the same logic I guess.

Comment: I see, ok thanks. One last thing, can the username and the password for the session be set on the settings file as well?
Currently, I set it in the code itself.